# Open new console window

Tags: go

What is some code I can use so that my golang program can open a new console window?

I have one program A running program B, and so there is no console window for program B (the stdin and stdout is used for interaction with program A). I want program B to display user-friendly information in a new console window (along with program A’s console window) so that it is easy to see what is going on.

Comment: We can't answer this without knowing which operating system you're using.  We also aren't going to write your code for you. Show your attempt, and explain what specific problems you're having.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The below code would work on Ubuntu, it is a sample program that echoes the input unless you type "new console" in which case executes itself again in a separate console.

It does that by executing:

```
gnome-terminal -e <program>
```

Note that this might be OS specific, as each OS flavour would have a different way of opening a new shell window.

For example, in Windows it seems the same can be achieved using:

```
cmd /C start <program>
```

(though I am not able to test that right now)

Sample working program for Ubuntu:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "bufio"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
    "log"
)

func main() {
    progPath, err := os.Executable()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(`Enter text to echo (or "new console" to open a new console)`)
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
    for scanner.Scan() {
        text := scanner.Text()
        if text == "new console" {
            cmd:= exec.Command("gnome-terminal","-e", progPath)
            cmd.Start()
        } else {
            fmt.Println(scanner.Text())
        }
        fmt.Println(`Enter text to echo (or "new console" to open a new console)`)
    }
}
```

Comment: On macOS, you can achieve the same thing with `xterm -e <program>` and after installing `urxvt` with homebrew, `urxvt -e <program>`. The native xterm (and urxvt) windows look kinda ugly so you might want to customize them by specifying a couple more options ;)